# How to remove all commas before certain characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a string such as

```
var x = "This is as,] sent,}encee:. Doo} youu: likei} i,:t."
```

I wanted to know if there is any way to remove all characters that come before either `]`,`}`, or `:`? This would result in

```
"This is as] sent}encee:. Doo} youu: likei} i:t."
```

I know I could probably loop through the string, but do you guys know what any simpler ways?

**EDIT**: Sorry how would you address this if you only wanted to replace the `,` that come before `]`,`}`, or `:`?

Comment: Instead of capturing the character like the others show, you can also use a lookahead to make the `,` match conditional on the next character. `x.replace(/,(?=[\]}])/g, "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with javascripts regular expression replace:

```
x.replace(/,([\]\}\:])/gi, '$2')
```

`\,` will capture one character

`([\]\}\:])` will capture the next character if it is a `]`,`:` or `}`

The `gi` will make it global search and case-insensitive.

```js
var x = "This is as,] sentencee,:. Doo,} youu: likei,} it."
var y = x.replace(/,([\]\}\:])/gi, '$1');
document.write(y);
```

Comment: Just replace the `\w` with `,`. I made a change to my snippet to illustrate it

Answer (score 1):

### Regex Replacement

Replace with a regex looking for a comma followed by your specific character, and replace them with the special character (e.g., `",:" => ":"`).

```js
var x = "This is as,] sent,}encee:. Doo} youu: likei} i,:t.";
x = x.replace(/,([\]:}])/g, "$1");

alert(x);
```

### String Replacement

You could also use the following string replacement method, chaining replacements, but it's important to note that the global replace flag (`"g"`) won't work in v8 JS engine, like Chrome (and I think Safari), so use this method with caution:

```js
var x = "This is as,] sent,}encee:. Doo} youu: likei} i,:t.";
x = x.replace(',]', ']', "g")
     .replace(',}', '}', "g")
     .replace(',:', ':', "g");

alert(x);
```